# How to use JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile() to generate a JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a jasper report. It worked in my Netbeans ide but after compiling it doesn't work and doesn't show an error. After reading this [Jasper report is not working after making jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679230/jasper-report-is-not-working-after-making-jar-file) I changed my code to this.

```
InputStream path = getClass().getResourceAsStream("\\my_package\\ChartOfAccounts.jasper");
HashMap param = new HashMap();
String cpname = cmpName();
String cpadd = cmpAdd();
param.put("CompanyName",cpname);
param.put("Address", cpadd);
JasperReport  jr = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, param, conn);
JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer (jp,false);
jv.setTitle("Chart of Accounts");
jv.setVisible(true);
```

but when i use

```
JasperReport  jr = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
```

it says I should use a string type variable there. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.html
there are several methods for loading objects. JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile takes String as an argument and in the code above an InputStream is passed which causes the error.

Based on the use case you should consider which method to call.
If you need to use InputStream you should use [JRLoader.loadObject(InputStream)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.html#loadObject-java.io.InputStream-)
If you need to read from a file (which is external to the program and does not live on the classpath) you should use [JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.html#loadObjectFromFile-java.lang.String-)